# definition of separation axioms in topology

Tags: general-topology, definition, intuition

I am learning the Separation Axioms and came across the definition of regular space. In the definition they say, "Suppose the one point sets are closed in $X$"

My question is: how can one point sets be closed in any case? Can't you always find an open neighborhood around them? Is there any way of looking at this intuitively?

Answer (score 2):

A one-point set is closed if its complement is open. In $\Bbb R$, for example, $\{x\}$ is closed for any $x\in\Bbb R$, because $\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$ is open: if $y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$, there is an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $y\in(a,b)\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$. In particular, if $y<x$, then $y\in(y-1,x)\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$, and if $y>x$, then $y\in(x,y+1)\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$.

Now suppose that $X=\{0,1\}$ with the open sets $\varnothing$, $\{1\}$, and $X$; this is the [*Sierpiński space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), and in it the one-point set $\{1\}$ is **not** closed, because its complement, $\{0\}$, is not open.

If $X$ is any space, and $x\in X$ is any point of $X$, then of course $X$ is an open nbhd of $x$ and an open set such that $\{x\}\subseteq X$; this has nothing at all to do with whether or not $\{x\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the case $\Bbb{R}$.  Take a point $b$ on the real line, then clearly the two rays that make up the complement of $\{b\}$ form an open set.

The reason one-point sets closed is part of the hypothesis to regularity and normality (sep axioms; at least in one definition), is so that we can have the inclusion:

Normal spaces $\subset$ Regular spaces $\subset$ Hausdorff spaces

Let's look at the proof that every regular space is Hausdorff using the definition:

**Def**. $X$ is regular if one-point sets are closed and for all closed sets $C$ and points $p \notin C$ their exist two disjoint neighborhoods containing $C$ and $p$.

*Proof*. Since one point sets are closed, then let $C = q$, the second point, and we're done.

Thus, as you can see the one-point set closed property makes the proof one line.

Also, let's look at the proof that every normal space is regular.

Again, since one-point set are closed, in the definition of normal, which is:

**Def**.  $X$ is a normal space if one-point sets are closed and for any two disjoint closed sets $C,D$ in $X$, there are two disjoint open sets containing them.

we can let $C = p$ since one point sets are closed, and we're done.

That's why one-point sets closed is used in the definitions of regular and normal.